# Decode JSON and php. Works with variable, not as URL

Tags: php, json

I'm new to json decoding with php. here's my situation. I need to grab a very simple json call and parse it on my HTML page. Here's the contents of that json:

```
[{"id":"793","date":"Apr. 18, 2011","title":"the cat in the hat","url":"http:\/\/www.somesite.com\/community\/blogs\/id-793"},{"id":"788","date":"Apr. 12, 2011","title":"the fox has sox","url":"http:\/\/www.somesite.com\/community\/blogs\/id-788"}]
```

etc...

When I go ahead and put that in a string in my php file:

```
$json = [{...}]
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($arr as $item) {
    echo "title: ". $item['title'] ."<br>"; 
}
```

I get the titles printed out w/o a problem. If, instead, I put:

```
$arr = json_decode("url_path_here",true);
foreach($arr as $item) {
    echo "title: ". $item['title'] ."<br>"; 
}
```

I get an error, "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() " and the array is simply empty.

The feed is on a different server during development, if that matters. I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm using PHP 5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`json_decode` takes a string, not a URL.

This will likely work:

```
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents("url_path_here"),true);
foreach($arr as $item) {
    echo "title: ". $item['title'] ."<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Just to note: sometimes PHP won't be setup to allow URLs in file functions. If that's the case you may need to use curl instead.

Comment: thanks for the head's up on that. If it doesn't work on the destination server, I'll check that first.

Answer (score 3):

`json_decode()` takes the JSON to decode. If you want to decode JSON from a remote server then you will need to pull it down first before feeding it to the function.

Comment: thanks! that explains it. ceejayoz's solution worked perfectly